# How to build Windows 10 appxupload(ready to submit to store) package by command line

Tags: msbuild, windows-store-apps, package, windows-10, win-universal-app

Tried with msbuild command line as `msbuild App1.sln /t:Publish /p:Configuration=Release` and also tried as described in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2014/02/12/create-a-windows-store-appx-package-and-sign-it.aspx, only appx packages are built which cannot be used to submit to store.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add the `/p:AppxPackageIsForStore=true` parameter.

Comment: I've tried this but App1_StoreKey.pfx and Package.StoreAssociation.xml are not generated as package built by VS

Answer (score 1):

We're using option: `/p:UapAppxPackageBuildMode=StoreUpload`

There's a good related blog post here:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2016/01/08/windows-store-app-projects-stopped-generating-the-appxupload-file-after-installing-vs-2015-update-1/

And some more specific documentation from [Microsoft](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/windows/universal) on this option